# How to change texture of an object to a new texture via a trigger

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I Have a trigger in my game and want to change the texture when the player enters a certain area.  I have set up the trigger but can't get the image of the waal (object) to change?

Here is the code i am using:

```
var Wall1: GameObject; \\Existing Game Object
var wall1TC: Texture; \\Texture to change Existing Game Object to.


  function OnTriggerEnter() {

     GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("Wall_New_Texture", Texture);

  }
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here?

Can some one please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for changing wall material texture -

```
var Wall1: GameObject; \\Existing Game Object
var wall1TC: Texture; \\Texture to change Existing Game Object to.

function OnTriggerEnter() {

    Wall1.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = wall1TC;

}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! It's working now!!  Can't believe it was that simple!